# Why does やすい conjugate to やすく in 分かりやすくいえば?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, adjectives, adverbs, i-adjectives

I was wondering how やすい becomes やすく in 分かりやすくいえば?

Here is the full sentence:

> 分かりやすくいえば あいつらにとって葉山は友達で

Answer (score 2):

*i*-adjectives like やすい turn into adverbs via the rule

> *-i* → *-ku*

for example

- やす**い** → やす**く**
- 早**い** → 早**く**
- 新し**い** → 新し**く**

The *i*-adjective やすい can attach as a suffix to the *masu*-stem of a verb like 分かる, but the result 分かりやすい is grammatically still an *i*-adjective and in the phrase

> 分かりやすくいえば

分かりやす**く** is an adverb for the verb いう (here in the form いえば). (Similarly, 早**く**いう "to say/speak quick**ly**" etc.)

Simple =)